# Is there a way to get the users current Flash settings (for the camera)?

Tags: ios, camera

The Camera app persists settings for the user as to whether the flash is off / on / auto (and stuff like is HDR enabled).  Is there a way to read these settings so that I can have my app (which has custom camera UI) default to the last known user's preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure here but if you look at the UIImagePickerController documentation you will see there is an API for cameraFlashMode. I am not positive if it is a readable property but if it is, that has 3 values of:

```
enum {
   UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff  = -1,
   UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto = 0,
   UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn   = 1
};
typedef NSInteger UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode;
```

So you can just check the values of it and then do whatever you want in your app accordingly.

Comment: OP wants to be able to read the Camera App's settings, or some global system-wide camera setting. This would be useful if he were persisting the settings his user sets in his own app.

Comment: Yep, I didn't test if this was a readable property but it seems like it is not. This most likely means that it isn't possible then.